# Is there a way to find out whether a generic type is integer and count all elements inside the collection that are even

Tags: c#, generics, binary-search-tree

I wrote my on generic class for Binary Search Tree, I need to define a method that searches for all even numbers in a Tree. Here is how i define a tree:

```
class BST<T> : ICollection<T> where T : IComparable<T> {

    public int CountEven() {
        if (root != null) return ccount(root, 2);

        return 0;
    }

    private int ccount(Node root, int div) {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);

        if (itemType == typeof(int) && root != null) {

            if (root.data % div == 0) {
                //error: operation / cannot be applied to operands of type T and int
                return 1 + ccount(root.left, div) + ccount(root.right, div);
            }

            else { return ccount(root.left, div) + ccount(root.right, div); }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that a more appropriate approach would be to write a method in a separate class, accepting a `BST<int>` as a parameter. It could potentially be an extension method. I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, even for private methods.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error, you could adjust your if statement:

```cs
if (itemType == typeof(int) && root?.data is int intData)
```

Afterwards you can work with the int typed variable `intData`.

Also, I guess you are using the wrong operator for the even check. You should use something like that:

```cs
if (intData % div == 0)
```

Combined your `ccount()` method should look something like:

```cs
private int ccount(Node root, int div)
{
  Type itemType = typeof(T);
  if (itemType == typeof(int) && root?.data is int intData)
  {
    if (intData % div == 0)
    {
      return 1 + ccount(root.left, div) + ccount(root.right, div);
    }
    else
    {
      return ccount(root.left, div) + ccount(root.right, div);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: compiler says : " T cannot be made nullable" and underlines root?.data is int intData as a mistake

Comment: @R.Khamazaev Regarding the `root?.data is int intData` underlining: this feature is available in C# 7 and later versions. See [Type testing with pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching). Which version are you using?

Comment: @Astrid E. i use VS2022 . See my answer below, that one works

Comment: @R.Khamazaev Okay. The only difference between the `... is int intData` expression is the `?` after `root`; I hope you will give Gabriel some credit for their suggestion, seeing as your own answer without a doubt seems to be inspired by contents in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int CountEven()
{
    if (root != null)
        return  ccount(root, 2);
    return 0;
}

private int ccount(Node root, int div)
{
    Type itemType = typeof(T);
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    if ( itemType == typeof(int) && root.data is int intData)
    {
        int add = 0;
        if (intData % div == 0)
            add = 1;
            return add+ ccount(root.left, div) + ccount(root.right, div);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're answer could be improved by a brief description on how and why it works, or even some inline comments in the code you've posted.